# can not initialize data from prop

Tags: vue.js

here is my child component:

```
export default {
  name: "SnackBar",
  props: ["show", 'msg', 'progress'],
  data: () => ({
    show2: this.show,
  }),
}
```

and its template:

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-snackbar
      v-model="this.show2"
      :multi-line="true"
      timeout="-1"
    >
      {{ msg }}
      <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
        <v-progress-circular
          v-if="progress"
          style="float: right"
          indeterminate
          color="red"/>
        <v-btn
          color="red"
          text
          v-bind="attrs"
          @click="show2 = false">
          Close
        </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

and I use it in the parent :

```
<SnackBar :show="snackbar.show" :msg="snackbar.msg" :progress="snackbar.progress"/>
```

the problem is that the show2 data is not defined:, here is the console log:

```
Property or method "show2" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

**[from official docs:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)**

> The prop is used to pass in an initial value; the child component
> wants to use it as a local data property afterwards. In this case,
> it’s best to define a local data property that uses the prop as its
> initial value:
>
> ```
> props: ['initialCounter'],
> data: function () {
>   return {
>     counter: this.initialCounter
>   }
> }
> ```

I am doing exactly the same thing, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the arrow function for the data property loses the vue component context, try to use a simple function :

```
export default {
  name: "SnackBar",
  props: ["show", 'msg', 'progress'],
  data(){
    return {show2: this.show,}
  },
}
```

or try out this :

```
export default {
  name: "SnackBar",
  props: ["show", 'msg', 'progress'],
  data: (vm) => ({
    show2: vm.show,
  }),
}
```